# ¿Qué sucede con los parámetros de tipo "formación"?

Tags: c++, abogado-del-lenguaje

Estoy enfrentándome a una duda acerca de cómo C++ trata a las formaciones pasadas como parámetro y no logro encontrar la parte del [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) que regula o especifica el tratamiento a recibir.

En C++ una formación abierta es una formación<sup>1</sup> cuyo tamaño no ha sido ni va a ser especificado, en inglés se conoce como *array of unknown bound* o *unbounded array* y NO debe ser confundida con las formaciones cuyo tamaño se deduce en tiempo de compilación:

```
int valores[] = { 2, 3, 4 }; // 'valores' contiene exactamente tres elementos.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {} // 'argv' es una formación abierta
```

En el ejemplo anterior, `valores` no es una formación abierta porque se conoce su tamaño (aunque dejemos que el compilador lo calcule por nosotros) mientras que `argv` es una formación abierta porque ni especificamos tamaño ni se puede deducir el tamaño en tiempo de compilación.

#### Formación por copia.

Cuando pasa una formación como parámetro en una función, suceden cosas curiosas, supongamos que tenemos las siguientes funciones:

```
#define CHIVATO std::cout << f << '\t' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';

void formacion100(int f[100]) { CHIVATO; }
void formacion200(int f[200]) { CHIVATO; }
void formacion_abierta(int f[]) { CHIVATO; }
void puntero(int *f) { CHIVATO; }
```

Con el siguiente `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int cien[100]{};
    int doscientos[200]{};
    int *puntero_entero{};

    formacion100(cien);
    formacion200(cien);
    formacion_abierta(cien);
    puntero(cien);
    std::cout << '\n';
    formacion100(doscientos);
    formacion200(doscientos);
    formacion_abierta(doscientos);
    puntero(doscientos);
    std::cout << '\n';
    formacion100(puntero_entero);
    formacion200(puntero_entero);
    formacion_abierta(puntero_entero);
    puntero(puntero_entero);

    return 0;
}
```

Obtenemos como salida:

> ```
> 0x7ffec91a58a0    void formacion100(int *)
> 0x7ffec91a58a0    void formacion200(int *)
> 0x7ffec91a58a0    void formacion_abierta(int *)
> 0x7ffec91a58a0    void puntero(int *)
>
> 0x7ffec91a5580    void formacion100(int *)
> 0x7ffec91a5580    void formacion200(int *)
> 0x7ffec91a5580    void formacion_abierta(int *)
> 0x7ffec91a5580    void puntero(int *)
>
> 0x000000000000    void formacion100(int *)
> 0x000000000000    void formacion200(int *)
> 0x000000000000    void formacion_abierta(int *)
> 0x000000000000    void puntero(int *)
> ```

Podemos ver que la información de tamaño de la formación se ha perdido en cada llamada y que la firma de la función ha pasado a ser en todos los casos `void(int *)`, por un lado esto no es sorprendente ya que el estándar establece que esto puede suceder (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 4.2 Conversión de formación-a-puntero
>
> Un valor izquierdo o derecho de tipo “formación de `N` `T`” o **“formación abierta de `T`” puede convertirse en un valor derecho puro de tipo “puntero a `T`”**. El resultado es un puntero al primer elemento de la formación.

Lo que me preocupa es que el estándar especifica que una formación puede convertirse en puntero pero no indica que un parámetro pueda ser convertido de la misma manera hasta el punto de cambiar la firma de una función; para saber si realmente se está cambiando la firma de la función podemos nombrar todas las funciones igual y ver si se produce ambigüedad:

```
void F(int f[100]) { CHIVATO; }
void F(int f[200]) { CHIVATO; }
void F(int f[]) { CHIVATO; }
void F(int *f) { CHIVATO; }
```

Y efectivamente, el compilador ya indica que las funciones son la misma:

`CLang`

> ```
> error: redefinition of 'F'
> void F(int f[200]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: previous definition is here
> void F(int f[100]) { CHIVATO; }
> ```

`GCC`

> ```
> error: redefinition of 'void F(int*)'
> void F(int f[200]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: 'void F(int*)' previously defined here
> void F(int f[100]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> error: redefinition of 'void F(int*)'
> void F(int f[]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: 'void F(int*)' previously defined here
> void F(int f[100]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> error: redefinition of 'void F(int*)'
> void F(int *f) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: 'void F(int*)' previously defined here
> void F(int f[100]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> ```

Tanto CLang como GCC consideran que la función `void(int[100])` es en realidad `void(int *)` y tratan cualquier otra función con *firma parecida* como un duplicado de la primera.

#### Formación por referencia.

El compilador no se toma la libertad de cambiar el tipo de datos de los parámetros cuando pasamos formaciones por referencia:

```
void formacion100(int (&f)[100]) { CHIVATO; }
void formacion200(int (&f)[200]) { CHIVATO; }
void formacion_abierta(int (&f)[]) { CHIVATO; }
void puntero(int *const &f) { CHIVATO; }
```

Al hacer este cambio perdemos la libertad de pasar formaciones o punteros indiscriminadamente:

```
int cien[100]{};
int doscientos[200]{};
int *puntero_entero{};

formacion100(cien);
formacion200(cien);                // No se puede inicializar int[200] con int[100]
formacion_abierta(cien);           // No se puede inicializar int[] con int[100]
puntero(cien);
std::cout << '\n';
formacion100(doscientos);          // No se puede inicializar int[100] con int[200]
formacion200(doscientos);
formacion_abierta(doscientos);     // No se puede inicializar int[] con int[200]
puntero(doscientos);
std::cout << '\n';
formacion100(puntero_entero);      // No se puede inicializar int[100] con int *
formacion200(puntero_entero);      // No se puede inicializar int[200] con int *
formacion_abierta(puntero_entero); // No se puede inicializar int[] con int *
puntero(puntero_entero);
```

Si eliminamos las llamadas que producen error:

```
int cien[100]{};
int doscientos[200]{};
int *puntero_entero{};

formacion100(cien);
puntero(cien);
std::cout << '\n';

formacion200(doscientos);
puntero(doscientos);
std::cout << '\n';

puntero(puntero_entero);
```

Obtenemos:

> ```
> 0x7fff6761dfc0    void formacion100(int (&)[100])
> 0x7fff6761dfc0    void puntero(int* const&)
>
> 0x7fff6761dca0    void formacion200(int (&)[200])
> 0x7fff6761dca0    void puntero(int* const&)
>
> 0x000000000000    void puntero(int* const&)
> ```

Es decir: las funciones no han sido convertidas a `void(int *)` si no que han conservado su firma, pero aún siendo la firma diferente siguen causando ambigüedad como si `int[TAMAÑO]` e `int *` fuesen equivalentes.

```
void F(int (&f)[100]) { CHIVATO; }
void F(int (&f)[200]) { CHIVATO; }
void F(int (&f)[]) { CHIVATO; }
void F(int *const &f) { CHIVATO; }

int main()
{
    int cien[100]{};
    int doscientos[200]{};
    int *puntero_entero{};

    F(cien);
    F(cien);
    std::cout << '\n';

    F(doscientos);
    F(doscientos);
    std::cout << '\n';

    F(puntero_entero);

    return 0;
}
```

`CLang`

> ```
> error: call to 'F' is ambiguous
>     F(cien);
>     ^
> note: candidate function
> void F(int (&f)[100]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: candidate function
> void F(int *const &f) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> error: call to 'F' is ambiguous
>     F(doscientos);
>     ^
> note: candidate function
> void F(int (&f)[200]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: candidate function
> void F(int *const &f) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> ```

`GCC`

> ```
> error: call of overloaded 'F(int [100])' is ambiguous
>      F(cien);
>            ^
> note: candidate: 'void F(int (&)[100])'
> void F(int (&f)[100]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: candidate: 'void F(int* const&)'
> void F(int *const &f) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> error: call of overloaded 'F(int [200])' is ambiguous
>      F(doscientos);
>                  ^
> note: candidate: 'void F(int (&)[200])'
> void F(int (&f)[200]) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> note: candidate: 'void F(int* const&)'
> void F(int *const &f) { CHIVATO; }
>      ^
> ```

Para mayor confusión, si `int[TAMAÑO]` e `int *` son equivalentes a ojos del compilador, no deberíamos haber tenido errores al llamar a la función `formacion_abierta` con `int[100]`, `int[200]` o `int *`

#### Dudas.

Mis dudas no tienen tanto que ver con el por qué sucede esto (puedo imaginar varios motivos por los cuáles los compiladores podrían decidir comportarse así) mis dudas son principalmente sobre el estándar de C++ y dónde especifica las normas a seguir cuando se pasan formaciones como parámetros de función (en especial las formaciones abiertas); sin embargo aunque estoy esperando encontrar (sin éxito) alguna pista en el estándar, otras fuentes que aclaren mis dudas serán bienvenidas:

- ¿Por qué en formaciones pasadas por copia se cambia la firma de la función para eliminar el dato del tamaño de la formación?
- ¿Por qué las formaciones abiertas, según si son pasadas por copia o referencia aceptan o rechazan ciertos argumentos de entrada?
- ¿En qué parte el estándar de C++ describe lo que debemos esperar al pasar formaciones como parámetros?

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Por qué en formaciones pasadas por copia se cambia la firma de la función para eliminar el dato del tamaño de la formación?

Aquí confluyen varias características:

**1. Optimizaciones**

Porque desde sus cimientos, C++ está pensado para ofrecer el máximo rendimiento posible. Para conseguir ese resultado necesita aprovechar, forzosamente, todos los comportamientos indefinidos posibles. De esta forma el compilador se puede permitir el lujo de omitir cientos de comprobaciones.

En este escenario de comportamientos indefinidos entra en juego el eliminar el tamaño del array. La primera dimensión del array es totalmente prescindible ya que el offset entre un elemento y el siguiente viene determinado por el resto de dimensiones (o el tamaño de un puntero es un array de una dimensión). C++ simplemente no necesita el tamaño de la primera dimensión y por eso, siempre que puede, lo ignora. Nota que el resto de dimensiones solo importan a la hora de calcular la posición de cada elemento. Así, ante unas líneas como éstas:

```
int tablero[FILAS][COLUMNAS];
tablero[3][4] = 10;
```

El compilador hace una traducción tal que:

```
int * ptr = tablero;
*(ptr + 3 * COLUMNAS + 4) = 10;
```

En resumen. El compilador no solo necesita la primera dimensión sino que además el programa resultante tampoco va a verificar que el algoritmo no exceda los límites del array. Al ser un valor totalmente innecesario salvo para la reserva de la pila y su posterior liberación, el valor puede ser ignorado.

Como veremos hay otra característica que refuerza que la primera dimensión sea ignorada.

**2. Tipos equivalentes**

Todos sabemos que un array **no es** un puntero, o al menos no un puntero tradicional, ya que no puedes reasignarlo ni modificar el tamaño de la memoria gestionada por el mismo.

Sin embargo no hay muchas diferencias entre una región de memoria de la pila y una región de memoria dinámica. Cuando se hace una reserva de memoria el sistema devuelve un puntero a un bloque de memoria concreto (todos los bytes son adyacentes)... exactamente igual que en el caso de un array. La única diferencia radica en la región donde se encuentran los datos (*heap* o montón y *stack* o pila). Lo único que hace el puntero es almacenar la posición de memoria del inicio de la reserva.

**3. Conversión estándar**

El estándar contempla la conversión estándar de un array a un puntero (traducción de la casa):

> § 4.2 Conversión Array-a-puntero [conv.array]
>   Un L-value o R-value de tipo "Array de N elementos de tipo T" o "Array de tamaño desconocido de tipo T" puede ser convertido a un PR-value de tipo "puntero a T" El resultado es un puntero al primer elemento del array.

Recordemos que las conversiones estándar son implícitas.

En este punto conviene recordar que los punteros no dan información sobre el número de elmentos, así pues la conversión de array a puntero quedaría así:

```
int array[10];
int * puntero = array;
```

Nota que la dimensión del array se pierde.

¿Y qué sucede si el array tiene dos o más dimensiones? En este caso el tipo del array es compuesto, por lo que el tipo del puntero también tiene que serlo. Para que el puntero pueda saltar de un elemento a otro debe conocer el tamaño de cada elemento y, para ello, necesita conocer todas las dimensiones del array (menos la primera que ya hemos visto que no es relevante):

```
int array[10][15];
int(*puntero)[15] = array;
```

Aquí vemos, aunque la sintaxis sea un poco fea, como estamos declarando un puntero a `int[15]`, es decir, cada elemento del puntero ocupará el espacio de 15 `int`.

**4. Los arrays no se copian**

Los arrays son variables que **no disponen de operador de asignación**, luego no es posible copiar el contenido de un array en otro de forma directa:

```
int array1[10];
int array2[10];
array2 = array1; // error
```

Sí que admiten, en cambio, operaciones de asignación sobre sus elementos. En estos casos las reglas las marcará el tipo de dato sobre el que se realiza la asignación (si el tipo no dispone de operadores de asignación tampoco se podrán copiar los elementos uno a uno):

```
struct SinCopia
{
  SinCopia & operator=(SinCopia const&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  SinCopia array1[10];
  SinCopia array2[10];

  array2[0] = array1[0]; // Error, no existe operador de asignación
}
```

Resumiendo, esta característica impide, por defecto, que los arrays puedan usarse literalmente como parámetros de las funciones.

** Conclusión **

Las conclusiones son las siguientes:

- El tipo array, como tal, no puede usarse como parámetro de una función porque no podemos copiarlo
- Disponemos de una conversión *array a puntero*.
- El tipo *puntero* no da información sobre el número de elmentos (la primera dimensión sobra)
- Si el *puntero* es de un tipo compuesto (un array de varias dimensiones), dicho tipo debe contener todas las dimensiones del array, excepto la primera)

Así que juntando todo, o se prohiben los arrays como parámetros de funciones o se convierten automáticamente a un puntero. Se ha optado por la segunda opción, ya que es perfectamente viable e implícita (gracias a la conversión estándar).

> ¿Por qué las formaciones abiertas, según si son pasadas por copia o referencia aceptan o rechazan ciertos argumentos de entrada?

Como hemos visto en el punto anterior, un array no puede ser pasado por copia, ya que no se pueden copiar, y se convierte implíctamente en un puntero.

Las referencias son harina de otro costal por una sencilla razón: no estás haciendo una conversión sino que estás conservando el tipo original del array.

C++ posee un tipado fuerte y al declarar un array destás haciendo uso de un tipo. Dos arrays de tamaños diferentes poseen tipos diferentes y, al no existir una conversión entre ambos tipos, el compilador no encontrará una alternativa viable y generará un error en tiempo de compilación.

> ¿En qué parte el estándar de C++ describe lo que debemos esperar al pasar formaciones como parámetros?

Técnicamente en ninguna, o al menos yo no la he encontrado como tal, pero tal y como se explica en el primer punto, el comportamiento explicado es la única opción viable que permite que el código compile correctamente.

Comment: La parte de la aritmética de punteros está descrita en el [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en los apartados "*5.2.1 Subscripting*" y "*8.3.4 Arrays*".

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus el ejemplo lo he puesto únicamente para demostrar por qué no es necesario conocer la primera dimensión del array :)

Comment: Me parece bien, tan sólo amplío información ya que parte de la pregunta se basa en conocer el estándar.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus entonces tiene sentido que edites la respuesta y añadas esa información en su sitio. los comentarios son poco llamativos